# How to make the python package PyDEA work?

Tags: python, package

I downloaded the package pyDEA (https://pypi.org/project/pyDEA/), but when I try to run it using the command pyDEA nothing happens and when I use python -m pyDEA.main_gui I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject> File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
'File' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
'return' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
'File' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    exec(code, run_globals)
'exec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyDEA\main_gui.py", line 15, in <module>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    from pyDEA.core.utils.run_routine import RunMethodGUI
'from' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyDEA\core\utils\run_routine.py", line 4, in <modul
e>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    import xlwt
'import' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwt\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    from .Row import Row
'from' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 9, in <module>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    from . import ExcelFormula
'from' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwt\ExcelFormula.py", line 8, in <module>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    from . import ExcelFormulaParser, ExcelFormulaLexer
'from' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\xlwt\ExcelFormulaLexer.py", line 53, in <module>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    _re = recompile(
'_re' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 252, in compile
'File' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    return _compile(pattern, flags)
'return' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\re.py", line 304, in _compile
'File' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
'p' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_compile.py", line 764, in compile
'File' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
'p' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_parse.py", line 958, in parse
'File' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    p.state.flags = fix_flags(str, p.state.flags)
'p.state.flags' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>  File "C:\Users\Gebruiker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\sre_parse.py", line 925, in fix_flags
'File' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>    raise ValueError("cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern")
'raise' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>ValueError: cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern
'ValueError:' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I still use this package? I am python version 3.9. Are there maybe any other efficient ways to solve a DEA problem using python without actually having to formulate the LP?

Comment: How do you run it? Their docs (at least on PyPI) is bit confusing - they use `>>` when in fact they want terminal/shell and agan `>>` when import in different python code.

Comment: Also, the package is not updated since 2017, so there **might** be compatibility issues with 3.9

Comment: I just run it using the 'python -m pyDEA.main_gui' command in the terminal

Comment: The output you show is really strange, because every line starts with the prompt `C:\Users\Gebruiker\PycharmProjects\pythonProject>` and it try to execute a Traceback, line by line. Also, when you say you run the command in the terminal, do you mean the integrated terminal inside IDE (PyCharm)?

Comment: Yes I use PyCharm.